# Mail only being sent from one email sender

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

Having a weird issue here friends.
I have installed phpMailer for my codeigniter application using this link https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer

It seems to be working. But when first installed I provided sample email for sender... johny@domain.name
That worked.
But since, It only works with this sender email address.
If lets say for instance I use andy@domain.name it is not sending.
Result is true as successful, but no messages come through.

This works...

```
    <code>
    $result = $this->email
            ->from('johny@*****.com','Email from tester')
            ->to('samantha@*****.com') // some other domain than sender
            ->subject('This is test')
            ->message('Test message')
            ->send();
        var_dump($result);
</code>
```

This doesn't...

```
<code>
$result = $this->email
        ->from('mark@*****.com','Email from tester')
        ->to('samantha@*****.com') // some other domain than sender
        ->subject('This is test')
        ->message('Test message')
        ->send();
    var_dump($result);</code>
```

Both result in success, but only first one successfully sends the message.
Also there is no errors in server error.log

Has anyone ever run into this? What was the solution?
Thank you.

Comment: A fake `From:` would make it undeliverable with most providers, regardless of which transfer you configured (lack of detail there makes this unanswerable, btw). Obligatory reference: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](//stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)

Comment: What's in your `mail.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to update, apparently there is nothing wrong with above code.
But there was some sort of massive lag on my mail server or my mail client app.
All the messages I had missing got to my junk mail inbox hours later.
I still see the lag at this time, tho not as long as previously but still 10-15 minutes.

Anyway, if you get to this exact point, then first check your mail.log
on ubuntu it is located most likely in..

```
<code>
/var/log/mail.log
</code>
```

If all is well in there, then advise to search elsewhere not your code.
I suppose check your with receivers mail-provider(in case of testing it is probably yours) or your mail client. (in my case it is outlook )